# Speed up maven war plugin

Tags: performance, maven, maven-war-plugin

The maven plugin works very slow for me. In my project the webapp folder has nearly 15000 small files (images, jsp, css, etc). When I assemble it with the maven, it first copies all files to the `target/myProject-1.0.0` directory, then builds `myProject-1.0.0.war` file from it. The copy process takes 10 minutes, building the `.war` takes 2 minutes.

As I see the build could be much faster if the `.war` file will be assembled straight from the webapp folder. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Straight from the `src/main/webapp` folder? Then what about depenencies, resources, etc?

Comment: @maba Sure, why not? The jar.exe could archive files from multiple locations. The ant task `<war>` does the trick easily.

Comment: It's not the maven way. You could use the [`maven-antrun-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) to use that ant task.

Comment: @maba Not sure what is wrong with the maven way, it's just matter of performance optimization - how to build an artifact in most efficient way.

Comment: What if you try with parallel builds. According to [**Parallel builds in Maven 3**](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/parallel-builds-in-maven-3.html) the `maven-war-plugin` is supported.

Comment: @maba Parallel build is to use several CPU cores. My problem is to copy 15000 files, which is I/O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you use the use the `war:inplace` goal of [`maven-war-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/inplace-mojo.html) together with a custom [`maven-antrun-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/index.html) task.

The `war:inplace` will generate the webapp in the WAR source directory. It will create all necessary extra folders under `webapp`.

The `antrun:run` can be customized to create the war according to your special requirements.

This will potentially improve the performance since most of those resource files you have will still be in the `webapp` folder and not being copied.

Comment: It saves some of the absurd copying but war:inplace also copies all libraries into WEB-INF/lib, which is also unneccesary and troublesome. 8-( Did anybody actually try this?

Answer (score 5):

In the configuration section for the war plugin, use warSourceExcludes to exclude unneeded files and directories. In the example below, the directories components and node_modules will be excluded from the exploded war as well as from the final war. In my case this reduced the build time from 3 minutes to 14 seconds.

```
        <configuration>
              <warSourceExcludes>
                components/**,
                node_modules/**
              </warSourceExcludes>
        </configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just want to mention that there is a [`useCache`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#useCache) setting which significantly increases performance (~3 minute instead of 12). However it is acceptable for development only, not for CI-server which should always do clean builds.

Comment: Could you include your Maven configuration that achieved what you describe here?